# What is the difference between sqlite3_bind_text, sqlite3_bind_text16 and sqlite3_bind_text64?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 C interface. After reading document at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html , I am totally confused.

What is the difference between sqlite3_bind_text, sqlite3_bind_text16 and sqlite3_bind_text64?

The document only describe that sqlite3_bind_text64 can accept encoding parameter including SQLITE_UTF8, SQLITE_UTF16, SQLITE_UTF16BE, or SQLITE_UTF16LE.

So I guess, based on the parameters pass to these functions, that:

sqlite3_bind_text is for ANSI characters, char *
sqlite3_bind_text16 is for UTF-16 characters, 
sqlite3_bind_text64 is for various encoding mentioned above.

Is that correct?

**One more question:**

The document said "If the fourth parameter to sqlite3_bind_text() or sqlite3_bind_text16() is negative, then the length of the string is the number of bytes up to the first zero terminator." But it does not said what will happen for sqlite3_bind_text64. Originally I thought this is a typo. However, when I pass -1 as the fourth parameter to sqlite3_bind_text64, I will always get SQLITE_TOOBIG error, that makes me think they remove sqlite3_bind_text64 from the above statement by purpose. Is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `sqlite3_bind_text()` is for UTF-8 strings.
- `sqlite3_bind_text16()` is for UTF-16 strings using your processor's native endianness.
- `sqlite3_bind_text64()` lets you specify a particular encoding (utf-8, native utf-16, or a particular endian utf-16). You'll probably never need it.
- `sqlite3_bind_blob()` should be used for non-Unicode strings that are just treated as binary blobs; all sqlite string functions work only with Unicode.

Comment: Thank you very much. I add an update to my question regarding the document. Can you please help on that?

Comment: The documentation certainly reads like the text64 version requires an explicit byte count, yes.